# Advice on Literature pertaining to transient pipe flow with heat transfer and friction

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, heat-transfer, compressed-gases

For a project I am working on I need to model the flow of argon in a long pipe. The flow is transient in nature since the tanks and regulator from which it enters cause the mass flow to change. Moreover, it reaches low temperatures due to the Joule-Thomson effect. Hence convective heat transfer from the pipe to the gas occurs.

Any recommended literature would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how long is your pipe? and what do you expect to obtain from your model?

Comment: Depends on how much fidelity you need from the solution.  Does the gas temperature vary only along the axis of the pipe, or do you need the temperature gradient from the centerline to the pipe wall?  If temperature is uniform throughout the cross-section, then I would look at graduate-level text books on heat transfer.  "Heat Transfer" by A. F. Mills is one of my favorites.  On the other hand, if you need a transient 2D solution of the temperature profile, it may be outside the scope of a typical text book.  For that I would google "numerical gas flow in a tube" or something similar.

Comment: ["Finding things" questions are off-topic for the site.](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/10/16)  That said, I think you have a decent engineering question in here if you get rid of the resource request and focus on what you've tried and where you need help.  As noted by others, providing more details into the actual system would go a long ways towards getting answers that would help you.  Please [edit] those details into your question.